# How to slice smoked salmon really thinly?

Tags: knife-skills

I have recently decided to try to home smoke fresh salmon (FYI using a half-size school locker). Once I have the product, though, I am not sure how to slice it thinly, as it is commonly sold commercially.

I have a half-baked idea that I could freeze it, then run it through a slicer, but I am afraid the freezing (not to mention the cutting) might damage the flesh.

Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: I've never done this before, but there is a really good youtube video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9ET3rPJYpY

Comment: You are planning on cold smoking the salmon, right? A hot smoke (200F) will not get the same results as what you buy at the store.

Comment: [This is](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmkBn25IcL0&feature=relmfu) an even better vid

Comment: Both videos are cool. Forget about freezing, no need. Just need the right knife and practice. I haven't done smoked salmon, but have sliced marinated salmon and it wasn't that hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, chill it in the refrigerator overnight.  Preferably in the coldest part of the refrigerator (the bottom).   After that put it in the freezer just long enough to get stiff enough to slice thinly, but do not let it completely freeze.

The initial chill will help keep any ice crystals that form inside the cells small, thus decreasing the risk of the meat getting mushy.

Comment: It has taken 3 years for me to acknowledge it but baka, you are the respondent with the info I was looking for. Kudos!